# Use different thumbnails size for an specific "archive page" of a category in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a great store made in woocommerce but thumbnails in archive pages for 2 of my 9 different categories are cropped too much since my thumbnails are vertical (700x900), this images for this 2 categories must be in horizontal, using 500x300 so the cropping doesn't affect the picture too much, is this possible?

For example I want to keep all categories to default thumbnails (700x900) but I need category ID 23 and 27 to use 500x300 thumbnails.

I found this code, but I cant make it work for woocommerce:

```
  if (in_category( '23' )) {
    // different size for one category
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 500, 300, true ); 
} else {
    // default size
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 700, 900, true ); 
}
```

I already added the custom image size and regenerated my thumbnails.

I will appreciate any help or clues how to solve this.

Comment: Have you regenerated your thumbnails after adding this code? If not, go to your WooCommerce status page, click on the Tools tab, and click the button called "Regenerate Images" or "Regenerate Thumbnails". After setting the thumbnail size, you have to regenerate the images, or alternatively re-upload the images to the post type.

Comment: Frits, yes I also verified that the new thumbnails have been generated and they are. I guess maybe the error is in the code, I do not how to implement the code in woocommerce. I put it in functions but It doesn't work that way, the output thumbnails are still 700x900. For example this is the output now with the code: http://mariaengracia.com/novias/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/AP1816-700x900.png I need the code to output http://mariaengracia.com/novias/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/AP1816-500x300.png but only for 2 specific categories.

Comment: Ok cool - have a look at changing `in_category('23')` to `is_product_category( array( 'sash', 'other-category-name' ) )`

Comment: I tried that it still does not work :( https://d.pr/i/hEMRIP  Maybe I need to use a hook?

Comment: Meanwhile since I already have the thumbnails created I am using a find and replace jquery script to change the images url, but I really wish there was a direct way because the page loads both thumnbails 700x900 and the 500x300 and that makes it heavier.